# findViewById() gives null pointer

Tags: nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have below code which is giving null pointer exception in obtaining editText3 at line 4.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Double result = intent.getDoubleExtra(MainActivity.RESULT, 0);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
editText3.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

Can some please let me know what is the problem. I tried doing clean build but it didn't worked.

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: your xml activity_result contains this button?

Comment: Yes. its a textBox not a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can double check if specify the wrong layout in setContentView() first.